# ios detect bluetooth state changes in terminated state

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I initialized CBCentalManager in my app. I see bluetooth state changes in foreground and background. But when I swipe/kill application from task manager. It's stopped and doesn't work. How can I detect bluetooth state changes when app terminated by user ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

When the app is killed by the user you cannot detect your bluetooth state. You can detect the bluetooth state when your app is active again.